# Trying to set a session variable with Zend_Session_Namespace, everytime NULL

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm running an application where in the controller I'm trying to set session variables using Zend_Session and Zend_Session_Namespace:

Bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initSession()
{
    Zend_Session::start();
}
```

SomeController.php

```
protected function updateQuestionViewsTotal($question)
{
    $userSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('QA_Session');

    if (! is_array($userSession->questionViews)) {
        $userSession->questionViews = array();
    }

    // create session array to contain the questions this
    // user has viewed.
    if(array_search($question->id, $userSession->questionViews) === false) {
        $question->views_total++;
        $question->save();
    }

    // ensure that this page is in the array
    array_push($userSession->questionViews, $question->id);
    $userSession->questionViews = array_unique($userSession->questionViews);
}
```

As you can see from above, I have within one of my controllers a method with an attempt to use session variables via Zend_Session_Namespace.

However, when I insert a var_dump on the second page load (refresh):

```
protected function updateQuestionViewsTotal($question)
{
    $userSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('QA_Session');
    var_dump($userSession));
    if (! is_array($userSession->questionViews)) {
        $userSession->questionViews = array();
    }
```

..Please note: this is AFTER I've run it once, so I'm expecting that the session variable has been set. Anyway on every occasion, it is NULL. So it would seem that the variable isn't being written to $_SESSION? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show where you are inserting data in your session.

Comment: I thought setting this variable was inserting data into the session variable? As above, I'm trying to set questionsView as an empty array. So on subsequent page loads it should be an array already. I don't have anything else. Is there something missing? Looking at the docs, do I need anything else in my code to set a session var? http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html

Comment: In that case I think you have to remove `in_array` condition.

Comment: I've updated to show the full method. The condition is there to check the first time as it will be something like NULL if it is undefined, it should be an array. I need the condition there to check but I don't want to reset it every time. Sorry, maybe you wanted to the see the rest. I understand now.

Comment: Change your condition to this `if (! is_array($userSession->questionViews) || ($userSession->questionViews == NULL))`

Comment: Well, !is_array(...) will still be true if it's NULL so the additional ==NULL would be redundant. Anyway, it appears to be working now even though I've made absolutely no change, I've no idea why. Perhaps restarting the session (closing the browser) made a difference, I'm not sure. Anyway, thanks for you suggestions. Hopefully all is well now.

Comment: It's ok.. but if all is not well than let me know..